# Rest controller, providing enum name but saving it's value in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, jackson-databind

My problem seems to be quite simple as well as complex at the same time. I have a class Display and it has an enum i.e DisplayMode.

```
public class Display {

  private DisplayMode mode;
  //getters and setters

  public enum DisplayMode {
    BIG("display.mode.big"),
    SMALL("display.mode.small"),
    MEDIUM("display.mode.medium");

    private String modeValue;

    DisplayMode(String modeValue) {
        this.modeValue = modeValue;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name() + "/" + this.modeValue;
    }

    public String getModeValue() {
        return this.modeValue;
     }
  }
}
```

Now, I have a rest controller which receives the Display in JSON, i.e

```
{"display": {"mode": "BIG"}}
```

And it's getting saved in MongoDB as

```
{"display": {"mode": "BIG"}}
```

What i want is, if receive the rest request Display as

```
{"display": {"mode": "BIG"}} or 
{"display": {"mode": "big"}} or anyCase insensitive value
```

it should be **saved in the database as**

```
{"display": {"mode": "display.mode.big"}}
```

When I want to read Display out via rest controller, it should be same as saved in the database.

Any solution using serilizers and deserializers oranything else. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@JsonValue` to save with value && `@JsonCreator` to desrialize.

```
@JsonValue
final String modeValue() {
    return this.modeValue;
}
```

For Deserialize:

```
@JsonCreator
    public static DisplayMode forValue(String v) {
        return Arrays.stream(DisplayMode.values())
                .filter(dm -> dm.name().equalsIgnoreCase(v))
                .findAny().orElse(null);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the return from value() return the modeValue field?

Comment: need to use @JsonValue

Comment: My question was connected to the previous version of your answer bit since you've edited it it's no more relevant.